# Compiled vim from source on Mac OSX and getting 'shell returned 127' error?

Tags: bash, vim, shell, compilation, macvim

On my Mac OSX 10.6 machine, I started to use MacVIM for vim. Then I noticed my terminal version was different to the MacVIM version (MacVIM was 7.3 and my terminal version 7.2)... I thought they used the same vim?

I need 7.3 for some of the features. So I set about wanting to update the terminal version. I basically cloned it using Mercurial (the perferred way according to the official site) and then did the usual to compile it. This did work and I now have 7.3 in my terminal. But, on some commands when exiting, I can this error:

```
/bin/bash: q: command not found

shell returned 127

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

...I've tried my hardest to try and fix this problem, but trying to reinstall MacVIM, deleting the vim in my /usr/local/bin and compiling again and I just can't get rid of this annoying error.

Can anyone possibly help me? Am I doing this all wrong? ...most of the time I will be using MacVIM, but it'd be nice for me to have it in the Terminal - exactly how I'd have it on my Ubuntu servers.

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure on the exact path, but somewhere a few folders deep into the `Applications/MacVim.app` folder is the `vim` executable that will also run in a terminal (Use the `-g` option to launch it in GUI mode).

You should be able to throw this in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias vim=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/vim
```

Comment: `alias vim=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/vim`

Answer (score 53):

`:!q` is not `:q!`. This is probably not a bug.

The error message you're seeing is is most likely the result of accidentally typing `:!q` instead of `:q!`, which would be user error, not a bug. `:!q` shells out to run `q`, and your shell (`bash`) is not finding such a command and bails with 127. (For comparison, you might try `:!true`, `:!false`, `:!vim %`, to get a feel of this.)

There isn't really a “fix” for this, and `!` is really useful for other purposes; maybe with more practice you'll make the typo less often. You could also try using `ZQ` instead of `:q!`; this has other disadvantages (a typo `ZZ` will instead save the file if it's edited, and `ZQ` specifically is a vim extension), but at least you see *this* error again.

The upshot here is basically check to make sure you typed in your commands right, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is the homebrew formula for vim. Try these settings for "configure" or just install homebrew and install vim from there.

```
system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}",
                      "--mandir=#{man}",
                      "--enable-gui=no",
                      "--without-x",
                      "--disable-nls",
                      "--enable-multibyte",
                      "--with-tlib=ncurses",
                      "--enable-pythoninterp",
                      "--enable-rubyinterp",
                      "--with-features=huge"
system "make"
system "make install"
```

Comment: what's with all the `system`s? why not just use a shell script?

Comment: homebrew is a package manager for osx. The system calls above are part of the formula which is a ruby script. See http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: I can't actually find the normal vim formula in the homebrew repository. All I find is macvim. Has it been removed?

Comment: looks like its gone. Do the alias thing I guess /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim